# GeoServer 2.20 can't apply style

Tags: geoserver, style

I've just installed GeoServer 2.20.4 on a Windows 10 system, and everything works OK, EXCEPT when I try to associate a style with a layer. When publishing a layer, a selection of *any* style shows a broken icon:

[image]

I've configured GeoServer instances since version 2.2, and never come across this problem. The WMS/WFS URLs display fine in QGIS or ArcGIS, just without styling of course. The output from the start.bat command even says that the global styles, as well as my workspace styles, are loading with no errors. Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Answer (score 0):

I probably should have taken Ian Turton's advice to study the log file but instead I doubled down on searching StackExchange. I finally deleted the "C:\Program Files\GeoServer\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib\marlin-0.9.3.jar" rasterizer, and the styling works now. Probably not the best answer for production use, though...