# GeoServer - broken style icon

Tags: geoserver, publishing

Do you happen to know why it happens and how to fix broken SLD style icon in layer's publishing settings? And may it affect anything?

[image]

Layer is visible in Layer Preview with the correct style.

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Answer (score 2):

It means GeoServer cannot produce legend graphics for that style. Most of the WMS will still work fine, but good chances are that the GetLegendGraphic call on that layer/style combination will fail.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Do you know why this happens and how to fix it? It is a simple style - solid filled polygon with a boundary. GeoServer version is 2.20.4. And the same style works fine on GeoServer version 2.18.2.

Comment: All styles on this GeoServer have broken icons in layer's settings page. Even Generic one. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the "C:\Program Files\GeoServer\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib\marlin-0.9.3.jar" rasterizer solved the issue for me as suggested on this [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/428868/geoserver-2-20-cant-apply-style?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue using 2.25-SNAPSHOT. One day these icons were showing ok and the next they were not. The only thing I had done in between was unticked Enable Global Services in Settings:Global.
I ticked that and the icons appeared again.
Repeatable solution, but I do not understand why.